# Verascrypt wipe

Tags: encryption

If I cut existing files into the encrypted Verascrypt container, do I still have to securely wipe the files, or is it a bad idea and better to just copy them and then wipe? What software should I wipe the original files with if that's better?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Yes, you should wipe the original file. 
If you're using an SSD, a simple discard/fstrim equivalent is better. Wipe operations are notoriously ineffective on SSDs; but AFAIK wear-leveling algorithms don't impact a discard/trim operation.

The answer depends (only in theory, I think) on the source file system implementation.

Most file systems simply manipulate the metadata for file operations (cut paste, copy, delete, rename, etc.). The fundamentals remain the same even when you go across file systems / mount points where data also needs to be moved.

In the source file system it still is similar to a delete operation (not a wipe). To use an analogy, it's **not** like a Word document where a cut-paste removes content from where you cut it - giving it a "wipe" like effect.

Comment: it's not a SSD and the file system is NTFS, so does that mean that just cutting it to the encrypted folder isn't enough, and I should instead copy it and then wipe? What software should I wipe the original files with if that's better? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. cutting it isn't enough on a regular HDD w/ NTFS. On *nix I use "shred", but for windows you might try any of the tools from here (I don't have direct experience): https://www.lifewire.com/free-file-shredder-software-programs-2619149